# ARM's Never eXecute feature in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to study the iOS feature in iPhone. Can someone please explain the ARM's **Never eXecute** and please provide an example.

Comment: Just use Google: "arm never execute". First link, Wikipedia, explains it all

Comment: @Michael, in the wikipedia article there is no word about iOS. This is a good question, +1.

Comment: it doesn't have to. NX is an ARM feature and not an iOS feature. it's like asking for the boiling point of water when a cook from McDonalds boils it, and then complaining that the wikipedia article on water does not mention McDonalds.

Comment: Well, it is an operating system that supports the NX bit or not, and takes advantage of it. I stick to my opinion. This is indeed a good question. There is not much on the Internet about how iOS handles NX bit.

Answer (score 3):

The **[Never eXecute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)** mechanism (**NX bit**) enforces that a memory page cannot be both writable and executable at the same time. This prevents adversary injected code execution.

The iOS platform supports **NX**. If iOS app binaries have been modified when the device is turned off, or if a attempts to modify a code page at runtime, the program execution is aborted.

Based on *Mobile Platform Security - N. Asokan*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain where did you get " that a memory page cannot be both writable and executable at the same time." ... I was reading the apple os security white paper in that it says that " ARM’s Execute Never (XN) feature, which 
marks memory pages as non-executable. Memory pages marked as both writable 
and executable can be used only by apps under tightly controlled conditions" ...  so it can be both readable and writable at the same time ?

Comment: Please provide me with an example where this NX function will be useful

Comment: I found it in the book I linked in my answer. Moreover, in my answer I also write why NX is useful. It defends against malicious code injection. More you can find in the linked wikipedia article. Everything is there.